# Provide Border to TextBlock in UWP

Tags: uwp, border, textblock

**How can I  add a border to TextBlock without wrapping it with any extra framework element?**
One approach I have tried is by wrapping TextBlock with Border but I don't want to add an extra UI element like a border.

Comment: if you dont want to add an extra ui element to it, you need to customize its template style which can be complicated for a beginer, and even in that case you will be adding border to its template so there is no other way to show a border with a border

Comment: Editing TextBlock Template is very complicated, so just make TextBlock inside Border control. That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, firstly, deeply nested elements isn't something to avoid unless you have specific issues. However, the most performant way of doing this is to overlay a transparent rectangle onto the `TextBlock` inside a `Grid`, like this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock Text="This is a textblock" 
               Margin="3" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" 
               StrokeThickness="1" 
               Fill="Transparent" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I need to use this TextBlock inside list view and with nested elements there is a slight delay while rendering  of List.

Comment: ListView has animation when items add or remove, may it cause slight delay?